# Why guess-solution to linear recurrence relation is exponential?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, self-learning, generating-functions

> Why guess-solution to linear recurrence relation is a  exponential?

Sir i am from mechanical engineering. I recently started studying discrete mathematics and algorithms out of self interest.

In solving Fibonacci recurrence relation, $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$. we assume $F(n) = x^n$, x is some variable. Why such guessing? I saw this type of function guessing in solving homogeneous linear recurrence relation. May I know is there any specific reason for this? Why not some other function?kindly clarify

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! It is not a polynomial, but an exponential function (the variable here is $n$, not $x$). It is guessed by analogy with  linear o.d.e.s with constant coefficient, of which such linear recurrences are the discrete version.

Comment: Inserting this function leads to a polynomial equation we can solve.

Comment: Because the solution to $a_n=\lambda a_{n-1}$ is $a_n=a_0 \lambda^n$. Obviously there is a bit more to it than that, but the first order recurrence is the basic model for more complex situations.

Comment: thank you for correcting me sir @Bernard

Comment: Note also that $Ax^n+Bx^{n-1}=\left(A+\frac Bx\right)x^n$ so for a fixed value of $x$ this is still constant times $x^n$. You can put $x^{n-1}$ instead of $x^n$ as a test function and you can check that you will get the same values of $x$.

Comment: Such a "guess solution" is sometimes called an [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz); these are common in the study of difference/differential equatons. What typically makes for a good Ansatz is that applying the relevant operators (such as the shift $F(n) \mapsto F(n-1)$) gives us a multiple of a function of the same type. In this case, taking $F(n) = x^n$ means that $F(n-1) = x^{-1} \cdot x^n$, which is a constant multiplying our original guess.